# Can two routes use the same controller action in SailsJs?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am writing sailsJs API and I need to **bind the following 2 routes to the same controller action:**

```
'GET /user/count': 'UserController.getUserCount',
'GET /user/count/:role': 'UserController.getUserCount',
```

And in the action I want to check whether a role is specified or not and send the total user count if not a role is specified and give the user count for a role if the role is specified. **The controller action will be as following:**

```
getUserCount: function(request, response){
    var role = request.params.role;
    var query = {};
    if (role != null){
        query.role = role;
    }
    User.count(query).exec(function countCB(error, count) {
        console.log('There are ' + count + ' users.');
        response.json(count);
    });
},
```

Is this possible to implement?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Are you facing any problem?

Comment: When I use the route with no request parameter will it give null for the variable 'role'?

Comment: I could not find any documentation or discussion on this. thats why I asked. thank you btw

Comment: Please try it. It should work.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if I'm unsure about if something will work or not, I compile my code and see if it will work or not and then test scenarios. don't over think things, and ask WHEN you get stuck, not on the off-chance that you MIGHT get stuck ;)

Comment: there is a problem with the first route though. route with 2 slashes seems not working.. `'GET /user/count'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed.

No issues in binding multiple routes to same controller action.